# how can i check active subscription in inapp purchase ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have an subscription based app.I have successfully integrate  in app purchase but problem is that same itunes account have multiple purchase

I have 3 subscription

**- 3 month
- 6 month
- 12 month**

## **problem**

I have purchase 3 month inapp purchase from maulik@go.com[app email] and my itunes Id maulik@itune.com [itunes email]. now i am logout from maulik@go.com[app email] but can't logout itunes email. now i login another user and i want to check which active subscription from maulik@itune.com [itunes]

**My requirement**
Only 1 subscription active only one account in my app

example 
1 . 3 month subscription maulik@iunes.com Now don't want to purchase another subscription maulik@itunes.com within 3 month.

Please help me .. help will be appreciated

thanks